# UITableView and Parse Data

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am having issues setting with Parse data and a UITableView. Everytime I run the application, whether on the simulator or my phone, the app stops working and the only thing the console shows is `(lldb)`. When checking the debugger, only following two lines of code are highlighted.

```
findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
```

and

```
self.timelineData = array as NSMutableArray
```

Both have the error: `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT,subcode=0x0)` and im not quite sure what that means...

Here are snippets of my code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    self.loadData()
}

func loadData()
{
    timelineData.removeAllObjects()

    var findTimelineData : PFQuery = PFUser.query()
    findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!)-> Void in
        if error == nil
        {
            println("No error")

            if let object = objects as? [PFObject!]
            {
                for object in objects
                {
                   self.timelineData.addObject(object)
                }
            }

            let array : NSArray = self.timelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
            self.timelineData = array as NSMutableArray

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
}
```

and these would be the cells that i'm trying to load, but the code never gets this far...

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    println("loading cell")

    let postCell : LocationTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as LocationTableViewCell

    let post : PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject

    postCell.imageView.image = post.objectForKey("currentLocation") as? UIImage
    postCell.userInfo.text = post.objectForKey("FirstLastName") as? String

    // Configure the cell...

    return postCell
}
```

for the full code: http://pastebin.com/MN7qcFhq

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

in your code just only replace

```
self.timelineData = array as NSMutableArray
```

to

```
self.timelineData = NSMutableArray(array: array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing an s in:

```
if let object = objects as? [PFObject!]
{
    for object in objects
    {
        self.timelineData.addObject(object)
    }
}
```

Should be:

```
if let objects = objects as? [PFObject!]
{
    for object in objects
    {
        self.timelineData.addObject(object)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried that, and only the error changed.. I still get an error, except this time, the error is: `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT,subcode=0xdefe)`

Answer (score 0):

Hey Buddy I got you on this one. I had the same issues but I got help and got it figured out.

This is your Load Function

Try this

```
  func loadData(){
        timelineData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

            var findTimelineData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className:"Sweets")
            findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock
                {
                    (objects:[AnyObject]! , error:NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error == nil
                    {
                        self.timelineData = objects.reverse() as [PFObject]


                        //let array:NSArray = self.timelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects

                        println(objects)

                       // self.timelineData = array as NSMutableArray


                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
    }
```

Then go to your

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

And change

```
let sweet:PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject
```

To This

```
  let sweet: PFObject = self.timelineData[indexPath.row] as PFObject
```

Whats going on is you are mixing some Obj C with Swift , the code you are following was probably written in Beta so make sure you go back and learn the differences. If you are still having problems check all your conditions if(error != nil) should not be in your code.